# How to run more than one threads sequentially

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on multi-threading.In my program i have three thread one  prints `hello1`,thread two prints `hello2` and thread three prints `hello3`. I am starting the the threads simultaneously.I want the output to be

> hello1 hello2 hello3 hello1 hello2 hello3 and so on...

but every time,I am  running the program its giving different outputs like 
hello2 hello1 hello3 ,hello1 hello3 hello2.
I want the output to be in a sequence of 1 2 3.
The code is given below

```
package javaapplication2;


public class ThreadDemo {

void MyThread() {
    boolean st = true;
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("hello " + 1);

                    wait();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    //thread 2
    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("hello " + 2);
                    //Thread.sleep(2000);
                    wait();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    //thraed  3
    Thread t3 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("hello " + 3);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

  t1.start();
    try{
        t1.join();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    t2.start();
    try{
        t2.join();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    t3.start();
    try{
        t3.join();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new ThreadDemo().MyThread();
}
}
```

Comment: what's the point of using threads if youre going to run them sequentially?

Comment: Are you just ignoring all the exceptions that result from calling `wait()` outside of a sync block?

Comment: You needed appropriate synchronization, have a look at CyclicBarrier class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Comment: Man do I HATE these sorts of questions.  They always seem like poorly formed multi-threading-101 college course questions because they make no sense and (as @Reimeus points out) negate the whole point of threads.

Comment: 'Run threads sequentially' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SynchronousQueue` and turn this into a relay race with each thread passing the stick to the next one. Only the thread with the stick gets to print its payload.

```
void go() {
    SynchronousQueue<Object> t1ToT2 = new SynchronousQueue<>();
    SynchronousQueue<Object> t2ToT3 = new SynchronousQueue<>();
    SynchronousQueue<Object> t3ToT1 = new SynchronousQueue<>();
    Object theStick = new Object();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                Object stick = t3ToT1.take();
                System.out.println("hello " + 1);
                t1ToT2.put(stick);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    });
    //thread 2
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                Object stick = t1ToT2.take();
                System.out.println("hello " + 2);
                t2ToT3.put(stick);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    });
    //thread  3
    Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> {

        try {
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                Object stick = t2ToT3.take();
                System.out.println("hello " + 3);
                t3ToT1.put(stick);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();


    try {
        t3ToT1.put(theStick);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or for an even more esoteric (but fitting) class, use [Exchanger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html).

Comment: Doesn't really change the code much, just replace the queues with exchangers.

Comment: @Kayaman ah, I see, exchange the stick for `null`... That indeed also works.

Comment: Not that it really makes any difference, I just remembered `Exchanger` and I've never used it for anything.

Comment: @Kayaman lol ikr, same for `SynchronousQueue` for me. Just thought it'd be fun to use for this answer.

Comment: Ah yeah it's a `SynchronousQueue`, I though it was some other `BlockingQueue`. Yeah, not much use for that either, except I do remember some question where it was involved with some `ThreadPoolExecutor` craziness.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are meant to improve the performance the program which happens when 2 or more threads runs in parallel to achieve a common goal. So, there is no point of running the threads sequentially. It's the same like you have 3 methods which are executing sequentially. There is no point to use threading in this case.

However, modify your program in below way to achieve your desired output :

```
public class ThreadDemo {
void MyThread() {
    // boolean st = true;
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("hello " + x);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    // thread 2
    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("hello " + x);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    // thraed 3
    Thread t3 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("hello " + x);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    t1.start();
    try {
        t1.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    t2.start();
    try {
        t2.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    t3.start();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new ThreadDemo().MyThread();
 }
}
```